# Selenium error on Ubuntu EC2: "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

Hello I have a simple python script just here :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php')

#Store url associated with the soccer games
url_links = []
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "match/cotes-")]'):
    url_links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))

print(len(url_links), '\n')
print(url_links, '\n')
```

This script run perfectly on my Ubuntu PC but when I try to run it from a ec2 ubuntu server It does not work.

Here is my EC2 config:

DNS public (IPv4) : ec2-3-21-128-62.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
ID d'AMI : ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20200611 (ami-0a63f96e85105c6d3)

I indicate that google chrome and chromedriver are installed on my EC2 server.

When I run the script from EC2 I have this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 17, in <module>
    url_links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 141, in get_attribute
    self, name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```